# I'm tyring to use a script to undo ALL CAPS in my text area

Tags: jquery, capitalize

I have a textarea that receives inputs in ALL CAPS, which is fine for most users. Some users need the text represented in a normalized fasion - with the first letter of each sentence capitalized and the rest lowercase.

I tried to adapt some suggestions from other SO threads, but somethings is missing. Help please!

Body

```
<form>
        <input value="Select all" onclick="javascript:this.form.finaltext.focus();this.form.finaltext.select();"  type="button">
        <input value="Clear All" onclick="this.form.finaltext.value=''" type="button">
        <input value="Normalize text" type="button"  id="normalize">
        <a href="#" id="copy-textarea"><input type=button value="Copy to Clipboard"></a><br>
        <br>
        <textarea id="finaltext" cols="80" rows="50"> </textarea>
        </form>
```

Script

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('#normalize').click(function capitalizeSentences(){

var capText = $("#finaltext").val();
capText = capText.toLowerCase();

capText = capText.replace(/\.\n/g,".[-<br>-]. ");
capText = capText.replace(/\.\s\n/g,". [-<br>-]. ");
var wordSplit = '. ';

var wordArray = capText.split(wordSplit);

var numWords = wordArray.length;

for(x=0;x<numWords;x++) {

    wordArray[x] = wordArray[x].replace(wordArray[x].charAt(0),wordArray[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase());

        if(x==0) {
            capText = wordArray[x]+". ";
        }else if(x != numWords -1){
            capText = capText+wordArray[x]+". ";
        }else if(x == numWords -1){
            capText = capText+wordArray[x];
        }               
}
capText = capText.replace(/\[-<br>-\]\.\s/g,"\n");
capText = capText.replace(/\si\s/g," I ");  
$("#finaltext").val(capText);
});
});
```

**UPDATE 1** Now the script works.

**NEW QUESTION** How can I manipulate the logic in the .replace brackets for the following situation:

The text area I want to allow "normalization" is in the following format:

> - TEXT1
> - TEXT2
> - TEXT3

with a dash, space and ALL CAPS text. The .replace logic seems to only look for the first character in the string, but I would like it to treat each line (starting with the dash) separately and only leave the first letter thereafter capitalized.

Comment: Sorry, when I click the 'normalize:button, nothing happens. I don't get any errors on chrome's debugger either.

Comment: Is your normalize button in the DOM at the time your event handler is declared for it?  If not you need to use `on` or `delegate` method - ex. `$(document).on('click', '#normalize', function(){ } );`  I don't know what your page name is otherwise I would have namespaced that event instead of to the whole document.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem with executing the click function. Thanks. I've updated my script.

Comment: @user1837608 Hey I'm glad I could help figure something out... I've been having a really rough time here lately.

Comment: @Ross and OP...  If that was the correct answer, then Ross should post it as an answer rather than a comment, the OP should accept it (and probably upvote it for being helpful) and the OP should then post the new question as a new question.

Comment: @Ben Barden Thanks for the suggestions.  At this point it might be better if the OP posts an answer to what fixed his original question and make a new question.

Comment: @Ross the OP just said that your suggestion was what had fixed his immediate problem (or at least, that's how it read to me).  I just figured you should get the credit for it.

Comment: @Ben Barden Thanks.  I'd be glad to give the OP an upvote to the answer if he wants to post it.  I'm not concerned about getting credit on this one, I'd rather the OP get it :~)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking the suggestion below and posting the corrected code that solved my click problem - credit to Ross:

I needed to wrap my script in a window.load function to include the function in the DOM after rendering.

```
$(window).load(function(){
...script...

}));
```