# Can someone explain this .replace logic?

Tags: jquery, replace, capitalize

I'm trying to adapt a script that converts ALL CAPS text in a text area to lowercase (with the first word capitalized). Part of my issue was resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658473/im-tyring-to-use-a-script-to-undo-all-caps-in-my-text-area/17661299#17661299).

It works, but... my textarea text is in the following format: dash, space, then TEXT.

- TEXT1
- TEXT2
- TEXT3

The script I have , and the .replace logic, do not account for the "-" and space, and it does not account for each line separately.

here is the script:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('#normalize').click(function capitalizeSentences(){

var capText = $("#finaltext").val();
capText = capText.toLowerCase();

capText = capText.replace(/\.\n/g,". [-<br>-]. ");
capText = capText.replace(/\.\s\n/g,". [-<br>-]. ");
var wordSplit = '. ';

var wordArray = capText.split(wordSplit);

var numWords = wordArray.length;

for(x=0;x<numWords;x++) {

    wordArray[x] = wordArray[x].replace(wordArray[x].charAt(0),wordArray[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase());

        if(x==0) {
            capText = wordArray[x]+". ";
        }else if(x != numWords -1){
            capText = capText+wordArray[x]+". ";
        }else if(x == numWords -1){
            capText = capText+wordArray[x];
        }               
}
capText = capText.replace(/\[-<br>-\]\.\s/g,"\n");
capText = capText.replace(/\si\s/g," I ");  
$("#finaltext").val(capText);
});
});
```

I don't follow the syntax or logic in the .replace() portions. Is there a primer on how the logic is constructed, or can someone give me a breakdown so I can adapt it more precisely?

Comment: Two words: regular expressions :)

Comment: So the logic in the .replace brackets follow Regex rules? or is .replace a RegEx command? This tutorial seems good, so I'll give it a sho: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Comment: See my answer for details!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some reading on RegEx and some trial and error, I have (*stumbled*) upon the solution to my problem.

I realized that most of the stuff in the script I adapted was irrelevant junk. So I stepped back and took the problem piecemeal.

First, I decided to render all the text in lowercase:

```
var capText = $('#finaltext').val();
capText=capText.toLowerCase();
```

then, I needed to use .replace to find all instances of "dash+space+any letter":

```
.replace(/- ./g,
```

This will find the one letter after the dash in all instances, then I combine with a function to make uppercase:

```
.replace(/- ./g, function(c){return c.toUpperCase();});
```

final code is:

```
$('#normalize').click(function capitalizeSentences() {
    var capText = $('#finaltext').val();
    capText=capText.toLowerCase();
    capText2 = capText.replace(/- ./g,function(c){ return c.toUpperCase(); });
    $("#finaltext").val(capText2);
});
```

See here - http://jsfiddle.net/fDy6K/

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in the code is the [literal format for regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). In the literal format you enclose your expressions inside slashes (`/`), and optionally add flags after the second slash.

Within your specific code example:

```
capText.replace(/\.\n/g,". [-<br>-]. ");
```

Is equivalent to

```
capText.replace(new RegExp("\.\n", "g"),". [-<br>-]. ");
```

Comment: Actually, now that I understand the expression better, I can see that the .replace expressions are completely superfluous to my specific needs. Those expressions find ends of sentences as defined by periods and spaces, and handle sentence beginnings. Since my textareas will not be populated by sentences as such, I should scrap that borrowed code and start from the beginning with replacing the first occurence of a letter following a dash and space, with an uppercase.